# execute command on files returned by grep

Tags: bash, vim, grep, find

Say I want to edit every .html file in a directory one after the other using vim, I can do this with:
`find . -name "*.html" -exec vim {} \;`

But what if I only want to edit every html file containing a certain string one after the other?  I use grep to find files containing those strings, but how can I pipe each one to vim similar to the find command.  Perphaps I should use something other than grep, or somehow pipe the find command to grep and then exec vim.  Does anyone know how to edit files containing a certain string one after the other, in the same fashion the `find` command example I give above would?

Answer (score 8):

```
grep -l 'certain string' *.html | xargs vim
```

This assumes you don't have eccentric file names with spaces etc in them.  If you have to deal with eccentric file names, check whether your `grep` has a `-z` option to terminate output lines with null bytes (and `xargs` has a `-0` option to read such inputs), and if so, then:

```
grep -zl 'certain string' *.html | xargs -0 vim
```

If you need to search subdirectories, maybe your version of Bash has support for `**`:

```
grep -zl 'certain string' **/*.html | xargs -0 vim
```

Note: these commands run `vim` on batches of files.  If you must run it once per file, then you need to use `-n 1` as extra options to `xargs` before you mention `vim`.  If you have GNU `xargs`, you can use `-r` to prevent it running `vim` when there are no file names in its input (none of the files scanned by `grep` contain the 'certain string').

<sup>*The variations can be continued as you invent new ways to confuse things.*</sup>

Comment: In my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS `-z` is spelled as capital Z. Quote from the manual: `-Z, --null - Output a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally follows a file name.` Checked Linuix Slackware 15.0 - also capital. Are you sure that the parameter should be spelled as small `z`?

Comment: @user4035: I'm pretty sure you're confusing a null byte after the file name with a null byte at the end of each line: • `-z`, `--null-data` — a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline; • `-Z`, `--null` — print 0 byte after FILE name.  This affects the output when processing multiple files (or when `-H` is specified): the file name is followed by a null byte (and then the line number and a colon if you specify `-n`) followed by the matching line.  I tested GNU grep 2.27 .  On macOS, the `-Z` option to BSD grep means "`-Z`, `--decompress` — Force grep to behave as zgrep."

Answer (score 0):

With `find` :

```
find . -type f -name '*.html' -exec bash -c 'grep -q "yourtext" "${1}" && vim "${1}"' _ {} \;
```

On each files, calls bash commands that grep the file with `yourtext` and open it with vim if text is matching.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a **for** cycle:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name '*.html'); do vim $i; done
```

This should open all files in a separate **vim** session once you close the previous.